# Add a header in all request coming out from my Xamarin application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin solution which has mainly 3 projects. One Android app, one IOS app and the common logic.

I would like to know if there is a global point where I could modify the user-agent header for all request coming out from the mobile applications. It could be also ok just to add a custom header for all request.

Any link or advice of how to do this?.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share code. It's hard to tell how you send requests. But of course it is possible.

Comment: You should be able to add a header to most of the Http clients available to make web calls. However, without any code, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 projects, you might have a Core project used to perform your requests. I suggest you to use the HttpClient (portable version) to send your request and use an HttpClientHandler to override the SendAsync method and add your custom header